# random outofmemory exception on c# list

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory

I have an application running the OCR Tesseract.
When the application finish the file's process, I make a query in the database to retrieve some data and fill a c# list (3134040 in UAT and more than 4000000 in production)
In Production, **sometimes** I hit an outofmemory exception. I really don't understand why it does not occur **frequently**.  I am suppose to retrieve more data days after days.
Over 20 times a month i hit the exception 4 times (and not subsequently). 
[image: Attached is what the part of code where the exception occurred]

When I am on debug mode I can reproduce the exception by giving this amount of data to my list: 33554432

Can anyone help me with some explication ?

Comment: There's a 2GB limit to the size of a single object.  You might be hitting that.  Also you should paste code into your question instead of a screen shot.

Comment: @juharr - unless these are structs, there's no way a 4 million item list is above the 2GB limit.

Comment: Try building for 64-bit only instead of Any CPU.  Though usually the real answer here is to process individual items in a streaming fashion rather than using giant world-sized chunks.

Comment: @hoodaticus True, but if it is a 'struct' it's very likely, also the OP only says more than 4 million, so it could be more, though I believe it has to be around 260 million in a 64-bit app and double that for 32-bit.  You're right that if it's running in 32-bit mode then the overall limit is 2GB and is a much more likely cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understand that sometimes i can hit a memory limit. On my dev env, when i fixe my data to 33554432 i have the outofmemory.. My big question is why in production it is random ?

Comment: You'd need to tell us a little bit more about the kind of application you have. Is it a web app? How do you do the hosting? Are there e.g. more applications running in the same application pool? Variable user load? Also, to fix this you might want to read up on "yield return": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: @dnickless thanks for the link.

Comment: @dnickless thanks for the link. It's a windows console app.
Hosted on a windows 2008 r2 server. The application uses an ocr engine to parse images.